# Solve $1^n+2^n+ \ldots +n^n=k!$ over positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**If $k,n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, solve the following equation
$1^n+2^n+ \ldots +n^n=k!$, where $k! $ denotes $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots k$.**

Comment: Note that since every integer $m \leqslant k$ is a factor of the RHS, it must be a factor of the LHS. What happens if we look at such $m$ for which $m \leqslant n$?

Comment: I found $n=1$ and no others but I can't prove this

Comment: Can Jihoon Kang give us his solution (or thoughts) ?

Comment: It can be seen that for The sum of any power  n of natural numbers we have $$ m(m+1) | S_n$$ if number of terms m of $ S_n$ is large enough. That is we must also have :$$ m(m+1) | k! $$. In this way k may be equal to m-j or m+j where j is an integer. So what is more important in here is the number of terms which can be arbitrary. I think finding an example of such a number by try and error can be helpful. For example for n=1 let number of terms m=100 then $$S_n=101 . 50=5050$$. Now we must see if 5050 is the factorial of a number or not.

Comment: We can also take the factorial of an arbitrary number and solve equation Sn = k!  for some values of n using standard formulas for Sn. if m is integer then the solution is found.

Comment: For example for n=1 if m =3 then Sn = 1+2+3=3(3+1)/2 = 6= 3!

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer, complete for $n$ even.*

Suppose $n\geq2$. Clearly, $k>n$.

Then $k!$ is even, so there is an even number of odd numbers on the left. So $n\equiv0,3\pmod4$.

Suppose $n\geq4$ is even. Odd squares are $1$ mod $8$, and $8\mid k!$, so $n/2$ is divisible by $8$. Odd $16$th powers are $1$ mod $32$ and $32\mid k!$, so $n/2$ is divisible by $32$. [...] Odd $4^m$th powers are $1$ mod $2^{2m+1}$ (Euler) so $2^{2m+1}\mid n/2$... etc, contradiction. (Boring details left out.)

Suppose $n\geq3$ is odd. Odd numbers have odd powers that are congruent to themselves mod $8$ and $8\mid k!$, so $8$ divides $1+3+\cdots+n=(n+1)^2/4$, so $n\equiv-1\pmod{8}$. Then odd numbers have $n$th powers that are congruent to their inverse modulo $32$ and $32\mid k!$, so $32$ divides $(n+1)^2/4$, so $n\equiv-1\pmod{16}$. From now this argument does not give anything new: $64\mid(n+1)^2/4$ only implies $n\equiv-1\pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer for $n$ odd, because barto above answered the question for $n$ even.

We have $1^n+2^n+ \ldots+n^n=1+(2^n+n^n)+(3^n+(n-1)^n) + \ldots \equiv 1 \pmod {n+2}$.

So, $k! \equiv 1 \pmod {n+2}$. If $k \geqslant n+2$, we have $k! \equiv 0 \pmod {n+2}$.

So, $n<k<n+2$, which yields $k=n+1$.

We have now $(n+1)! \equiv 1 \pmod {n+2}$.

If $n+2$ is a prime, let $n+2=p$ we have $(p-1)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and by Wilson $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$, so there are no solutions.

If now $n+2$ is not a prime, let $n+2=ab, (a,b)=1, a,b \leqslant n+1$ we have that $a,b \mid (n+1)! \Rightarrow ab \mid (n+1)! \Rightarrow n+2 \mid (n+1)!$, which is a contradiction.

So, we do not have solutions if $n \geqslant 3$ odd .

Comment: As a nitpick, you might want to change that last "which is impossible" to "which contradicts our original premise" or something like that. Just for clarity's sake.

Comment: Thank you. I am Greek and I can't handle English very well.

Comment: No problem! Wouldn't have known you weren't a native speaker if you hadn't mentioned it. ;)

Comment: should be $n+2$ is not a prime in the second to last sentence.

Comment: $n+2$ might still be a prime power, which would not equal $ab$ with $(a,b)=1$. However, with exception of small $n$, the sum will be larger than $(n+1)!$, which makes $k\ge n+2$.

Comment: @EinarRødland Can you prove $k \geqslant n+2$? If so, we are done. Also, the problem is from a Russian competition.

Comment: @knm: Have added proof of this as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplement to the answer by knm to show that $k\ge n+2$ (for large enough $n$).

Let $S_n=1^n+\cdots+n^n$. First, we show that $S_{n+1}/S_n>2(n+1)$. To do that, it suffices to show that $(r+1)^{r+1}/r^r>2(n+1)$ for all $r=0,\ldots,n$. Since the LHS is an increasing function, it has it's maximum at $r=n$, so we actually get
$$
\frac{(r+1)^{r+1}}{r^r} \ge \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}
> (n+1)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \ge 2(n+1).
$$
From this follows that
$$
\frac{S_{n+1}}{S_n} = \frac{\sum_{r=0}^n (r+1)^{r+1}}{\sum_{r=0}^n r^{r}}
> (n+1)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \ge 2(n+1).
$$

If $S_n>(n+1)!$ for some $n$, then if $S_n=k!$ we must have $k\ge n+2$.

However, if $S_n>(n+1)!$, then $S_{n+1}>2(n+1)S_n>(n+2)!$, so once we find one $n$ with $S_n>(n+1)!$, this is also the case for all larger $n$.

In particular, $S_3=36>4!$, so for all $n\ge3$ we have $S_n>(n+1)!$, which implies that $k\ge n+2$ if $k!=S_n$.